# Why does uniq! return nil if there are no duplicates

Tags: ruby, arrays, uniq

I'm just starting with Ruby and I personally find the following to be a violation of the "principle of least surprise".  And that is, quoting from [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002215), that uniq! "removes duplicate elements from self. Returns nil if no changes are made (that is, no duplicates are found)."

Can anybody explain this, which seems completely counter-intuitive to me?  This means that rather than being able to write one line of code below by appending .uniq! to end the first line, I instead have to write the following two lines:

```
  hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/)
  hooks = hooks.uniq
```

Or am I missing something, a better way?

EDIT:

I understand that uniq! modifies its operand.  Here's the problem illustrated better I hope:

```
  hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/)
  puts hooks.length #50
  puts hooks.uniq!.length #undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
```

I contend that the way uniq! works makes it completely senseless and useless.  Sure in my case as pointed out I could just append .uniq to the first line.  However later in the same program I am pushing elements onto another array inside of a loop.  Then, under the loop, I'd like to "de-dupe" the array, but I dare not write 'hooks_tested.uniq!' because it could return nil; instead I *must* write hooks_tested = hooks_tested.uniq

Indeed I contend this is a particularly egregious mis-feature in that it is a well known principle that, when devising a method that returns an array, one should always at least return an empty array, rather than nil

Comment: The POLS has a specific meaning with Ruby: "Does not surprise Matz (Ruby's creator).

Comment: Useless for the (incorrect) purpose to which you're trying to put it, agreed. Handy if you're trying to do something that - for example - tests the result of `uniq!`. That would probably be what Matz had in mind. ;-)

Comment: I agree. this is very PHP-esque (random, incongruous exceptional cases). all other cases, including `uniq` returns the original one. When `uniq` finds no duplicates, it returns the array itself. seriously wtf.

Comment: @MikeWoodhouse the method for that purpose should be `uniq?` not `uniq!`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `uniq!` modifies `self` and if `uniq!` would return a value you wouldn't be able to know whether a change actually occurred in the original object.

```
var = %w(green green yellow)
if var.uniq!
  # the array contained duplicate entries
else
  # nothing changed
end
```

In your code you can simply write

```
hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/)
hooks.uniq!
# here hooks is already changed
```

If you need to return the value of hook perhaps because it's the last method statement just do

```
def method
  hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/)
  hooks.uniq
end
```

or otherwise

```
def method
  hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/)
  hooks.uniq!
  hooks
end
```

Comment: The return values from "exclamation" methods are often arbitrary like this because they modify the object in-place. What's unfortunate about this case is some of the semantical mess it creates, as illustrated by your example: if uniq! then...actually not unique.

Answer (score 5):

The exclamation point on `uniq!` indicates that it modifies the array instead of returning a new one. You should do this:

```
hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/).uniq
```

or this

```
hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/)
hooks.uniq!
puts hooks.length
```

Comment: Typically, if you use the bang-form of a method it will be the only method acting on that particular object (i.e., not in a chain).  This is in part to eliminate ambiguous statements such as `hooks = hooks.uniq!.sort` or `hooks.uniq!.sort!` (where you can have what amounts to multiple assignments to the same variable in the same expression) or assignments to intermediate, temporary values such as `hooks.uniq.sort!`.  `Array.uniq!` also returns `nil` instead of `[]` so you can do things like `if (hooks.uniq!)` to modify the array and perform a special action if anything was changed.

Comment: You're second suggestion results in "undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass" if it hooks contains no duplicates -- this is precisely the unexpected behavior I am trying to draw attention to, but apparently it is falling on illogical -- er, deaf -- ears

Comment: Okay, sorry. If the second example doesn't work, there is something else going on here. What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Since Ruby 1.9, `Object#tap` is available:

```
hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/).tap do |hooks|
  hooks.uniq!
end
puts hooks.length
```

And perhaps more succinctly (h/t @Aetherus):

```
hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/).tap(&:uniq!)
puts hooks.length
```

Answer (score 2):

You can append `uniq` (no exclamation mark at the end) to the end of the first line.

Or, if you insist on using `uniq!`, use

```
(hooks = IO.read(wt_hooks_impl_file).scan(/wt_rt_00\w{2}/)).uniq!
```

Comment: yeah i guess i can in this case

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to why, but rather, a workaround.

Since `uniq` doesn't return `nil`, I use `uniq` and assign the the result to a new variable instead of using the bang version

```
original = [1,2,3,4]
new = original.uniq

#=> new is [1,2,3,4]
#=> ... rather than nil
```

Having a new variable is a small price to pay. It sure as hell beats doing if checks, with repeated complex calls to `uniq!` and `uniq` and checking for `nil`